# Change Router in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a link like below:

```
index.php/catalog/product/offer/id/1/cid/100/
```

- `id` param means the id of product
- `cid` param means the id of customer

Now if I want to change this link how to match with a router like:

```
index.php/offer/id/1/cid/100/
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a finite set of ID values you can create an equal number of [rewrite rules like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154521/gernerate-custom-urls-within-magento/4155090#4155090). The idea there is to map (ie. one-to-one) every possible URL to a shortened form.

---

However since the number of customers is out of your control it might be better to use a legacy XML rewrite as described [in the Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller).

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <vietean_catalog_product_offer>
                <from><![CDATA[#^offer/#]]></from>
                <to>catalog/product/offer/</to>
            </vietean_catalog_product_offer>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

---

If that doesn't work the third option is to form URLs like `index.php/offer?id=1&cid=100` which isn't as pretty. The URL will then translate into `offer/index/index`. Give your existing router the front name of `offer`, name the controller `IndexController` and the action `indexAction`.

```
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <vietean_example> <!-- This tag can be any unique value -->
                <use>standard</use> <!-- standard because it's the frontend -->
                <args>
                    <module>Vietean_Example</module>
                    <frontName>offer</frontName> <!-- First part of URLs -->
                </args>
            </vietean_example>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

The controller can access the URL parameters in the exact same way as before;

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->get('id');
$cid = $this->getRequest()->get('cid');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. 2nd option is good. I will try 1st.

Comment: Using 1st option, I got a problem is: I could not loadLayout and rederLayout properly? @clockworkgeek

Comment: What of the 2nd option? It should take only 5 minutes to test.

Comment: 2nd option is good. I just want to ask 1st option. I don't want to create more module just use as a router. Any idea for me, @clockworkgeek?

Comment: I cannot guess without seeing the relevant layout file and controller. That sounds like enough to be a separate question.